# Not clicking tabs TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a script below that clicks some buttons then it gives:

> line 41, in     clickMe = wait(driver,
>   15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))    line 
>   80, in until    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I've tried changing the xpath to `//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"]` and increasing wait time.

But it keeps giving this error message.
Any idea how I can get around this so I can click all the tabs on that page?

```
from random import shuffle

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.unibet.com.au/betting#filter/football')
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"]')

def page_counter():
    for x in range(1000):
        yield x

count = page_counter()

clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"]'))))
#//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"]
import collections
coupon_lables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"]')
coupon_lables = [index for index in range(len(coupon_lables))]
shuffle(coupon_lables)
links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in coupon_lables)
desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))
for key, index in desc_links.items():
    clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe)
    clickMe.click()
```

Comment: Can you post the html code for the tabs as I am not able to open your site.

Comment: @Murthi Try using a free proxy or vpn e.g Blockless (I think it region locks some people and set it to Australia). The html for tab is: https://pastebin.com/9zEwpt7q

Comment: It is blocked by our office firewall. I couldn't open any vpn or proxies here. It would be great if you add the code.

Comment: @Murthi I added the outerhtml of the tab in pastebin above, here is entirety of outerhtml: https://pastebin.com/eziGR7Pq

Comment: Try to increase implicit wait to 30sec

Comment: @AnkurSingh It's quite bizzare.  It seems to stop clicking part way through the job and then throw this timeout.  Increasing wait time did not solve.  Just waits very long time.